# I have problems with the connection of my embedded derby database, What's the problem?

Tags: java, database, connection, database-connection, derby

I was making this java application, it works fine in Netbeans but when I tried to use the .jar out of Netbeans the app doesn't load the db. I'm using the derby.jar to make the db. Also the main problem it's the connection class in the public Connection CargarDB()

I'm tried changing my URL and surrounding all the block with a Try...Catch and it's not working yet.

```
public Connection CargarDB(){
        Connection con;
        String barra = File.separator;
        String prjt = System.getProperty("user.dir") + barra + "Registros";

        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            String db = "jdbc:derby:" + prjt;
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);

            System.out.println("Base de datos cargada");
            return con;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error " + ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

It doesn't give an error in Netbeans but in the derby document in the dist folder show me this:

> -java.sql.SQLException: Database 'C:\Users\huevo\Documents\JAVA\Proyecto_T\dist\Registros' not found.
>   -Caused by: ERROR XJ004: Database 'C:\Users\huevo\Documents\JAVA\Proyecto_T\dist\Registros' not found.

I expect the output of my db show me the results in my JTable but it doesn't show anything

Comment: *C:\Users\huevo\Documents\JAVA\Proyecto_T\dist\Registros' not found.* - maybe fully path your DB.  It does not exist using a relative path

Comment: Yeah it works with the full path, thank you